# Making the arduino do the task based on value returned by a function in python

Tags: python, arduino

in the code below, function `openthedoor(set_accepted_list,set_list_ant_id)` returns a set of values called as `set_for_comparison`.Once you `print set_for_comparison`, you get a `set['5','8','32']`. I wrote an ardunio code to blink an LED whenever function`openthedoor(set_accepted_list,set_list_ant_id)` return some value. I call all the functions in the later part of the code. But when i run the code, the LED only blink once and then stops, eventhough the function is returning values. Any suggestions?

Python_code:

```
set_for_comparison = set()
def openthedoor(set_accepted_list,set_list_ant_id):
if len(set_accepted_list &  set_list_ant_id) >0:
    print"yes"
else:
    print"no"
set_for_comparison = set(set_accepted_list &  set_list_ant_id)
return set_for_comparison
```

I will use `set_for_comparison` for blinking the LED. The python code which uses the value returned for blinking the LED is shown below .

```
def code_controlling_gate(set_for_comparison):
connected = False
ser = serial.Serial("COM11",9600)   #for communicating with the arduino
while not connected:
    serin = ser.read()
    connected = True
ser.write('1')
while ser.read() == '1':
    ser.read()
ser.close()
```

Arduino code

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);  #baud rate
  pinMode(10,OUTPUT);  #output pin to connect arduino
  Serial.write('1');
}
void loop() { 
  while(Serial.available()<0){   
  digitalWrite(10,HIGH);
  delay(50);
  digitalWrite(10,LOW);
  delay(50);
  Serial.read();
  }
}
```

Comment: You python code print to Serial only once. Please check you code and formatting. Also: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @jikuja. Can you suggest how to solve it?

Comment: Solve formatting or code not being complete?

Answer (score 0):

Because you only call serial.write(1) in your setup(){...} so in your python script connected will only be true once per reboot of your arduino.

You need to call serial.write within the loop(){..}

Comment: I tried doing it, but it is not blinking the LED evenn once.